# Is there any way to get the information of the logged in user on node-red-contrib?

Tags: node.js, iot, node-red

Can I now get logged in user information when I'm on node-red-contrib?
And how to get it?
Example: I want to get logged in user in function.js node

Comment: Please do not delete and re-ask exactly the same question.

Answer (score -1):

No, because as I pointed out when you asked this earlier, flows execute even when there are no instances of the editor running (so there is nobody logged in).

Flows run in the backend, not in the browser, the browser is there purely to edit flows.

Comment: So do you know where the logged in user information on node-red is stored?

Comment: You need to ask a new question with a **lot** more detail about what you are trying to do, answering the questions I asked in the comment when you first asked this. What problem are you actually trying to solve, why do you think you need the Node-RED user information?